# What happens with download when signed url expires while downloading?

Tags: bintray

In Bintray, I can sign the url for download for a specific time, i.e. 600 secs. When a user starts the download process before expiry but the download takes longer so is over 600 secs.

1. User starts download by clicking at 530 secs.
2. The download will take approx. 5 minutes to finish.
3. 600 sec is arrived, will the download fail or continue on downloading?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expire is on the **download link** and not on the download of the file, therefore it will continue to download.

You will have to set the `valid_for_secs` attribute for the X amount of seconds you would like, for more information you can use the [Bintray's API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Bintray+REST+API#BintrayRESTAPI-URLSigning)